# How to install gdebi?

Tags: pantheon-terminal, package-management

I have a freshly installed system, and i've not been able install any third party software or packages via the terminal or software center. Please help me out[image: This is what happens when i try to install anything, or even update]

[image: This is another similar scene]

Answer (score 4):

You dont need 'gdebi' anymore...just open Appcenter and install [Eddy](https://github.com/donadigo/eddy).

Comment: But there are NO apps beyond the installed ones in app center! I tried updating the repo but the screenshots are testimony to what happens everytime. I can't find any specific app center setting like in Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Try these commands out.

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install gdebi

Those will let you install third party applications and repositories in the terminal.

Comment: software-properties-common is unnecessary for installation of apps present in the repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your error list in screen 1, it seems as if you have a DNS failure - perhaps check that you can reach, say apple.com, with Epiphany, and go from there.
HTH

Comment: Everything is working fine. I can open all the usual sites. I tried registering the mail client, it simply stays with a blank box. And then there is the terminal business.